# Postgres Auth failed, no pg_hba.conf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, postgresql

I've got an app that seems to be running just fine for the most part on Postgres (for Heroku), but now that I'm trying to do some fancier stuff like starting a delayed_job worker with

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job
```

I get this error:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<myusername>" (PG::Error)
```

This is troublesome, because

1. Installing postgres was a huge, confusing mess for me, as a Rails newbie, and I never remember setting a password. (I've got a password for PGAdminII, but I know that one, and this isn't it). When I go into my database.yml file and try to change the password to everything I can think of it being, it doesn't work.
2. Fishing around on the internet, it looks like I should do something to a pg_hba.conf file, but I don't have one anywhere, apparently.
3. I've been working on this app for weeks, and I really don't want to erase what I've got going on, so I'm wary of initdb'ing in another directory.
4. Database stuff makes no sense to me. I've tried to figure it out, but I think I'm just too new to this stuff. And I never know where to start to fix things.

This question is sort of vague cause I don't know enough to know what specific question to ask -- but can can anybody help me with this? Like: How do I figure out my password? What do I do about pg_hba.conf? Will I have to start a new database?

EDIT -- Per the below suggestions (Thanks!), I ran both "ps -A | grep postgres" and "ps -A | grep pg_ctl". The output of each, respectively, is

```
85 ??         0:06.94 postgres: logger process    
  101 ??         0:32.04 postgres: writer process    
  102 ??         0:23.98 postgres: wal writer process    
  103 ??         0:06.70 postgres: autovacuum launcher process    
  104 ??         0:07.60 postgres: stats collector process    
 6337 ttys002    0:00.01 grep postgres
```

and

```
6340 ttys002    0:00.00 grep pg_ctl
```

neither of which, unfortunately, appears to have anything preceded by -D.

Comment: What platform are you on? Installing PostgreSQL shouldn't be painful, but the specifics vary depending on your environment.

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX. It was painful because my computer had some inexplicable environment reset about two months ago, and suddenly everything -- Ruby, OpenSSL, etc -- was out of date. It was erroring all over the place, and since I'm new to command line and coding in general, I didn't really know what to make of it. Any ideas, though, what's going on with this password deal, or how to fix it?

Comment: OSX has two extremely easy options for PostgreSQL: [`brew install postgresql`](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) and [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/). What did you install? How did you get to the place you are at now?

Comment: [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) specifies how PostgreSQL should attempt to authenticate you. One was created by `initdb`, and as far as I know, it shouldn't be working at all without one -- unless somehow the filename was overridden using the `hba_file` configuration parameter. But again, I have no idea what your PostgreSQL install looks like, though I get the impression it's confusing.

Comment: I originally did Postgres.app. That didn't work, for the OpenSSL reasons. Then, since that wasn't working, I tried homebrew. That also didn't work, for whatever reason. And when someone was helping me fix all that, I ended up doing another install, using PGAdmin, I think. Yes. It's super confusing. There are probably remainders of all of the above everywhere, but I don't know how to 'clean up.' I now basically dread the word Postgres. But at any rate, any idea how to find whatever pg_hba type deal I've got going?

Comment: When I open PGAdmin and ask it to open pg_hba.conf (in its file menu), it opens up finder and just basically has me looking for conf files in my documents folder (where there are none). EDIT -- Just went looking for it. Searched my whole computer for ".conf" and came up with nothing with that extension !?!?! Should I just uninstall and reinstall with Postgres.app? Will that mess up my Rails app? How do I even do that?

Comment: PostgreSQL packaging on Mac OS X is a bit of a train wreck (http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/09/postgresql-packaging-on-mac-os-x-is-mess.html) so I don't blame you for being confused. It seems the various competing distributions don't really talk to each other. Inexperienced users land up  with three clashing half-broken PostgreSQL installs on their system. In your case you probably have more than one copy fighting over port 5432.

Comment: Chat room created, please join chat rather than a long conversation in comments here. See : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18207/postgresql

Comment: @Sasha Did you ever get anywhere with this? An update would be interesting; maybe consider answering this yourself if you found a resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately, don't think I have too much to add. I sat down with a wiser friend for an hour and uninstalled all the traces of my three pre-existing and non-functional PG installs, then reinstalled via homebrew. Works perfectly now, but I'm not sure exactly what was causing the problem in the first place. Just a lot of confusing permissions stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I can find my pg_hba.conf file in the path:

/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/